# Evento onkeydown não funciona no modo tela cheia (F11) no Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Tenho uma página que possui um cabeçalho. Eu gostaria de quando clicar no botão F11 (que deixa o navegador no modo Tela Cheia) o cabeçalho fosse ocultado da página e quando eu clicasse novamente, o cabeçalho voltasse a aparecer na página.

Quando eu clico a primeira vez na tecla F11, acontece tudo perfeitamente, a página entra no modo tela cheia já sem o cabeçalho. Porém, quando eu clico novamente na tecla F11, a página sai do modo tela cheia, porém o cabeçalho não volta pra página.  Se eu, depois disso, apertar novamente na tecla F11, a página entra no modo tela cheia com o cabeçalho.

Ou seja, o evento **onkeydown** não está funcionando em tela cheia.

Fiz um exemplo simples aqui que elucida a situação que estou passando com meu código (O tão pedido exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável). **Vejam:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>

</head>

<h1>Katie Bouman - Minha Namorada</h1>

<body>

  <script>
    document.onkeydown = function() {
      let codigo_unicode_tecla = event.keyCode;
      console.log(codigo_unicode_tecla);
      if (codigo_unicode_tecla == '122') {
        alert('Funcionou o click no F11');
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

- Na minha página, eu simplesmente verifico se o elemento HTML possui a classe d-none (do Bootstrap, que oculta um elemento) no momento do click na tecla F11. Se o elemento não possuir tal classe, então eu adiciono com o classList.add. Se ele possuir, eu retirou com o classList.remove. Essa é a dinâmica do código. Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Já tentou chamar `control+f11` ou `command+f11` e passar evento por parâmetro na função? `document.onkeydown = function(event) { ... }`

Comment: @IvanFerrer esse é exatamente o código da pergunta, o problema só ocorre no chrome. No MSEdge e Firefox funciona normalmente.

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer um botão para chamar uma função para estes eventos, em vez de usar a tecla, daí vc pode chamar essa função com a tecla também, e nem precisa se preocupar com evento onkeydown?

Comment: @IvanFerrer talvez ele queira detectar independente da forma, justamente pq não tem como saber o que o usuário vai usar, o evento fullscreenchange por exemplo não funciona com F11

Comment: Olá Gato de Schrödinger, atualizei a resposta, se não tiver necessidade de rodar em navegadores antigos existe a `@media (display-mode: fullscreen)`, ele funciona tanto quando entra em fullscreen com F11 quanto com `requestFullscreen`, só passei para lhe avisar, assim diminuirá sua necessidade sobre o JavaScript podendo controlar melhor o estilo diretamente no CSS.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esforço e por lembrar, @GuilhermeNascimento. Fico grato!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detectar o <kbd>F11</kbd> com o evento `keydown` esta funcionando perfeitamente no Firefox, aparentemente a falha ocorre somente no Google Chrome (e em navegadores baseados em Chromium), ainda que não tenha encontrado nada no [chromium/issues](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=f11%20event) sobre o problema (vou pesquisar mais e edito depois se necessário).

Também notei que o `:fullscreen` quando o modo é iniciado pela ação do <kbd>F11</kbd> **não funciona em nenhum navegador**.

Felizmente o **`@media (display-mode: fullscreen) {}`** funcionará para ambos casos, `Element.requestFullscreen()` e <kbd>F11</kbd>

Exemplo:

```css
#cabecalho-superior {
    ... aplica estilo para quando NÃO estiver em fullscreen ...
}

@media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) {
    #cabecalho-superior {
        ... aplica estilo para quando estiver em fullscreen ...
    }
}
```

Navegadores com suporte `display-mode: fullscreen`:

- Chrome 42+
- Edge 79+
- Firefox 47+
- Opera 29+
- Safari 13+
- Safari para iOS 12.2+

Como descrito em https://caniuse.com/?search=display-mode

Se por acaso precisar de suporte em navegadores mais antigos o único meio razoável será com JavaScript, e como o <kbd>F11</kbd> não trabalha bem nem com o `:fullscreen` e nem com o keydown (no Chrome) então o único meio será usar o evento `window.onresize` (ou com `window.addEventListener('resize', ...)`) e comparar `screen.width` com `window.innerWidth` e `screen.height` com `window.innerHeight`, claro que não há garantias sobre isto, pois dependendo de como o navegador ou sistema operacional se comportem é possível que nem terá as mesmas medidas, na pratica seria algo como:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', checarFullScreen);

function checarFullScreen()
{
     var cabecalho = document.getElementById('cabecalho-superior');

     if (screen.width == window.innerWidth && screen.height == window.innerHeight) {
         //Em fullscreen
         cabecalho.classList.add("d-none");
     } else {
         //Saindo do fullscreen
         cabecalho.classList.remove("d-none");
     }
}
```